# Lenovo Y50 Laptop drains battery in hibernating to 20% just 24hrs

Tags: windows-8.1, battery, hibernate, lenovo-laptop

I have a 6 months Lenovo Y Laptop and this is battery information is captured by BatteryCare
[image]

The problem is after I installed a fresh Win8.1 (yeah Superfish issue), Hibernating drains battery so bad almost 80% a day, it doesn't happen when I shutdown completely.

Not sure I miss something in config Power Option or something, please help me.

Comment: Do BIOS update this may solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows 8 has deprecated going directly to Hibernation; Sleep is preferred, which can be set to shutdown and save data after a given time, using the Power settings.
2. Windows 8 will try to wake from Hibernate for various reasons, including maintenance (disk optimization) and "Wake-on-LAN".

You might be best served by setting the computer to Sleep when power button is pushed or cover closed, and to Hibernate after a set time, allowing maintenance to complete.

Go to *Control Panel | Power Options | Edit Plan Settings* Select *Change advanced power settings* for the plan you're using, set *Sleep* and *Power buttons and lid* options as desired.

See [Windows 8.1: Sleep and Hibernation Settings](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows-8.1-sleep-hibernation-settings,2-737-3.html), for example, for more information.

BTW, this issue has nothing to do with the contemptible *Superfish* malware.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article, I think we shouldn't use Hibernate for SSD on Laptop.

It will drain batter life, increases Power On Count of SSD as crazy (29527 count for 208hrs Power On!) and SSD still working when hibernating (I can feel heat of SSD when open lid).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with Hibernation.

It takes ages to shutdown and then when it (finally) turns off you can hear the HDD constantly spinning up and then parking. It just does this all day and when you pull the laptop out of your bag you can feel the heat.

If it's an SSD you might not have noticed it accessing the drive however it will be rinsing power.